# Programming concept to dynamically define a function

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, python-xarray

I have the problem that I compute different evaluation measures of a model and a reference dataset - the datasets are used to be three-dimensional (x,y,t) and netcdf-data. The evaluation measures have to treated for four different types of temporal aggregation: no aggregation, aggregation over the whole period, aggregation with resampling (monthly) and aggregation in groups (hourlyovertime, monthlyoveryears).

The working horse I chose was python-xarray because they are very flexible with respect to netcdf handling.

Starting with the easy score BIAS I have the following code:

```
def BIAS_temporal(self,varns_result=None,aggregtime=None,dim_time=None):
    """ Compute the BIAS/ME for a timeseries -> e.g. R^3 --> R^2:
        BIAS(x,y) = SUM_{dim_t} ( MOD(x,y,dim_t) - OBS(x,y,dim_t) ) """
    def bias(x):
        return ( x[namex] - x[namey] )
    def biasmean(x):
        return ( x[namex] - x[namey] ).mean(dim=coordtime)
    #
    endresult = xarray.Dataset()
    for varnsproof,varnsref,varnsres in zip(self.varns_proof,self.varns_ref,varns_result):
        # rename the data variables and combine both datasets for evaluation
        namex=varnsres+"_x"; namey=varnsres+"_y"
        self.DSref.rename({varnsref : namey },inplace=True)
        self.DSproof.rename({varnsproof : namex },inplace=True)
        DScomb = xarray.merge([self.DSref,self.DSproof])
        coordtime     = self.MetricCalcProg.ListDimsToXarray(dim_time[varnsref])     #extract the name of time coordinate
        #
        if aggregtime == 'fullperiod':
            DSnew = biasmean(DScomb).to_dataset(name = varnsres)
            ...
        elif aggregtime == '-':
            DSnew = bias(DScomb).to_dataset(name = varnsres)
        elif "overperiod" in aggregtime:
            grpby_method=self.MetricCalcProg.ConvertAggregKey2Groupby(aggregtime)
            DSnew = DScomb.groupby(coordtime+'.'+grpby_method).apply(biasmean)
            DSnew = DSnew.to_dataset(name = varnsres)
            ... 
        elif "overperiod" not in aggregtime:
            resamplefreq=self.MetricCalcProg.ConvertAggregKey2Resample(aggregtime)
            DSnew = DScomb.resample(time=resamplefreq,keep_attrs=True).apply(biasmean)
            DSnew = DSnew.to_dataset(name = varnsres)
            ...
        #
        self.DSref.rename({namey : varnsref },inplace=True)
        self.DSproof.rename({namex : varnsproof },inplace=True)
        unitsnew=GeneralUtils.safe_access_bib('',KeyError,dicttest=self.DSref[varnsref].attrs,dictkey='units',errhandle=False)
        if unitsnew is None: unitsnew='-'
        longnew="temporal BIAS of "+str(GeneralUtils.safe_access_bib('', KeyError, dicttest=self.DSref[varnsref].attrs, \
            dictkey='long_name',errhandle=False))
        self.Update_Attributes(Datasetobj=DSnew,variable=varnsres,stdname=varnsres,units=unitsnew,longname=longnew)
        endresult = xarray.merge([endresult,DSnew])
    return endresult
```

As you see I need to define the functions 'bias' and 'biasmean' to get always proper results despite of the aggregation method 'aggregtime'. Defining another metric like 'LinearCorrelation' the code is nearly the same:

```
def LinCorr_temporal(self,varns_result=None,aggregtime=None,dim_time=None):
    """ Compute the linear correlation for a timeseries -> e.g. R^3 --> R^2:
        LinCorr(x,y) = ???"""
    def correl2dtm(x):
        a = ( x[namex] - x[namex].mean(dim=coordtime) ) * ( x[namey] - x[namey].mean(dim=coordtime) ) \
            / x[namex].std(dim=coordtime) / x[namey].std(dim=coordtime)
        return a.mean(dim=coordtime)
    #
    endresult = xarray.Dataset()
    for varnsproof,varnsref,varnsres in zip(self.varns_proof,self.varns_ref,varns_result):
        # ensure that only time stamps are considerd being present in both datasets (otherwise LC>1)
        self.DSproof = self.DSproof[varnsproof].where(self.DSref[varnsref].notnull()).to_dataset(name=varnsproof) #harmonize the nan's between both datasets (independent calculations would destroy lincor), part A
        self.DSref   = self.DSref[varnsref].where(self.DSproof[varnsproof].notnull()).to_dataset(name=varnsref)   #harmonize the nan's between both datasets, part B
        # rename the data variables and combine both datasets for evaluation
        namex=varnsres+"_x"; namey=varnsres+"_y"
        self.DSref.rename({varnsref : namey },inplace=True)
        self.DSproof.rename({varnsproof : namex },inplace=True)
        DScomb = xarray.merge([self.DSref,self.DSproof])
        coordtime     = self.MetricCalcProg.ListDimsToXarray(dim_time[varnsref])     #extract the name of time coordinate
        #
        if aggregtime == 'fullperiod':
            DSnew = correl2dtm(DScomb).to_dataset(name = varnsres)
            ...
        elif aggregtime == '-':
            print(' The Linear Corr. computation makes no sense for each single time step ')
            exit()
        elif "overperiod" in aggregtime:
            grpby_method=self.MetricCalcProg.ConvertAggregKey2Groupby(aggregtime)
            DSnew = DScomb.groupby(coordtime+'.'+grpby_method).apply(correl2dtm)
            DSnew = DSnew.to_dataset(name = varnsres)
            ...
        elif "overperiod" not in aggregtime:
                            resamplefreq=self.MetricCalcProg.ConvertAggregKey2Resample(aggregtime)
            DSnew = DScomb.resample(time=resamplefreq,keep_attrs=True).apply(correl2dtm)
            DSnew = DSnew.to_dataset(name = varnsres)
            ...
        #
        self.DSref.rename({namey : varnsref },inplace=True)
        self.DSproof.rename({namex : varnsproof },inplace=True)
        unitsnew='1'
        longnew="temporal lin. correl. of "+str(GeneralUtils.safe_access_bib('', KeyError, dicttest=self.DSref[varnsref].attrs, \
            dictkey='long_name',errhandle=False))
        self.Update_Attributes(Datasetobj=DSnew,variable=varnsres,stdname=varnsres,units=unitsnew,longname=longnew)
        endresult = xarray.merge([endresult,DSnew])
    return endresult
```

As you see, there are only minor differences compared to the 'BIAS' calculation. The function definition is different. The exception for the aggregation time '-' only occurs within 'LinCorr_temporal' and also the where-statement which selects only those grid points where 'notnull' data are present.

Do you have a suggestion to combine the both methods defined here with respect to the definition of the functions 'def bias' and 'def correl2dtm'? I guess there is a programming technique which I missed up to now, i.e. defining functions dynamically.

Comment: Is there a reason why the `bias` etc. functions are defined within the functions and not globally?

Comment: No, there is nothing which prevents from defining them globally. I only wanted to have the functions near their execution calls. Do you see a chance to call the bias-def, etc. dynamically if they are defined more globally? I would be interested in the technique behind that ansatz.

Comment: if they're defined globally, you could load them conditionally, e.g. `if is_bias: func = bias; else: func = correl2dtm`. If you truly want to define them dynamically, you can write a function that returns another function.

Comment: 'func=bias' loads the bias formula to the name 'func'? I will try it with a toy example. However, you suggested in the second sentence to write a function that returns another function. This concept is not known to me and maybe you have a link to an example where this is done.?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I have added a more verbose answer below. Let me know if that was what you were looking for

Comment: Why not create an "evaluator" class that generates these functions? Otherwise, I belive lambda's were implemented in large part for this reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects in python, so you can assign them to variables. You can pass them as function arguments:

```
def bias(x, namex, namey, coordtime=False):
    return (x[namex] - x[namey])

def correl2dtm(x, namex, namey, coordtime):
    a = (x[namex] - x[namex].mean(dim=coordtime)) * (x[namey] - x[namey].mean(dim=coordtime)) \
        / x[namex].std(dim=coordtime) / x[namey].std(dim=coordtime)
    return a.mean(dim=coordtime)

def temporal(self, func, varns_result=None,aggregtime=None,dim_time=None):
    ...
    DSnew = func(DScomb, namex, namey, coordtime).to_dataset(name = varnsres)
    ...

# call temporal() with bias function (= old BIAS_temporal)
temporal(bias, ...)

# call temporal() with correl2dtm (= old LinCorr_temporal)
temporal(correl2dtm, ...)
```

Comment: The Problem I see with the global definition is the arguments in the def-statements: 'namex', 'namey', 'coordtime'. In your example here, these arguments are defined in the method 'temporal(...)'. Does the def-statements know about the recent value of 'namex', ...?

Comment: You are correct, I didn't pay attention to that. I have updated the snippet now. As a general rule, it is always better to pass the arguments explicitly to the function instead of relying on globals.

Comment: This solution is fine because the xarray's support arguments for the apply functionality, i.e. they can passed to the function to be applied: `dataarray.resample(time="M").apply(bias,namex,namey,coordtime)`